# Getting a background url image next to h1 tag, not working

Tags: html, css, url, background

Im trying to accomplish the next situation;

If got a h1 tag, and right of it i want a small line (separator.png)
But my image keeps crossing the h1 text..
http://i57.tinypic.com/2m30l51.png

I've got a example of how i need it to be;
http://themes.webcreations907.com/ninezeroseven/option-two/#prettyPhoto

Those titles: "Take a Look, Recent Works"

HTML is like this;

```
        <div class="titleBar">
            <h1 class="left"><span>DIENSTEN</span></h1>
            </div>
```

CSS;

```
  #diensten .titleBar{
background:url('images/sep.png') repeat-x;
background-position:center;

}
#diensten .titleBar h1{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If tried a lot of things, even copied the code from the original site, but actually i have nog idea what to do.. Can someone help me with it?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

So i've tried all the things you guys answered.
So far none of them are working for me..

First;
The background tag, smart idea but my page background is transparant.. So transparant on transparant won't work. And even if i make the background transparent, the line will shine trough it. Are there any solutions to this problem? Because its a easy way to do it with a background tag.

Second;
Paulie_D's solution, i actually don't understand it.. Not advanced enough is guess, tried copying the exact code and change the parameters so it fits in my coding, but didn't work.. Can you help me making it fit my coding?

Answer (score 0):

Simply give your `h1` element a `background` of its own which matches the background of the page.

```css
#diensten .titleBar h1 {
    background: #f00;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You can then space the line apart from the `h1` element by introducing some right `padding` (which will extend the background past the end of the text):

```css
#diensten .titleBar h1 {
    ...
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: How would you do that on a transparant background? Two overlapping transparant bg's won't work..

Answer (score 0):

Your div titleBar is around the h1 title, I don't think using inline-block will solve this.
You should just wrap all around a div :

```html
<div class="titleWraper">
    <h1>DIENSTEN</h1>
    <div class="titleBar">
    </div>
</div>
```

and your css like this :

```css
#diensten .titleBar{
    background:url('images/sep.png') repeat-x;
    background-position:center;
    display: inline-block;
}
#diensten .titleWraper h1{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same kind of style. But the thing, they used some background color around h1 tag to avoid to show the stripped line(used as a background for titlebar). If you are ok with the effect do the following. Add your css like below and check the jsfiddle below.

```
.titleBar{
background:url('http://themes.webcreations907.com/ninezeroseven/option-two/wp-  content/themes/ninezeroseven/assets/img/theme/sep.png') repeat-x 0 55%;
background-position:center;
padding-top:0;
}
.titleBar h1{
display: inline-block;
background-color:#f2f2f2;
}
```

Jsfiddle link below..

http://jsfiddle.net/vapnF/

Comment: Thanks! Didn't notice that. That color trick might be a fast solution but if got a transparent background.. Got any tricks for that?

Answer (score 0):

A pseudo element will work although it does require an additional `span` but you can dispense with the image if required.

[**Codepen.io Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/DtwkF)

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="left"><span>Some Text</span></h1>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
  overflow:hidden; /* hides all extra pixels */
  font-size:2em;
}


h1 > span {
  diaplay:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

h1.left > span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left:100%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 1px; 
  width:2000px; /* some really large number*/
  background:red;
  margin-left:0.5em; /* or remove and add padding-right to span */
}
```

Comment: i actually don't understand it.. Not advanced enough is guess, tried copying the exact code and change the parameters so it fits in my coding, but didn't work.. Can you help me making it fit my coding?

Comment: Can you change your HTML to add the `<span>`?